# Asynchronously load JS

Tags: javascript, performance, pagespeed

We have our custom JS that are used by our clients on their websites. Is there any way to have the JS load asynchronously on my clients' websites (any configurations from our end) or it needs to be done only by our clients using a cache plugin?

JS Example - `<script src="https://cdn.domain.com/5670e553459091885818c74beba82.js"></script>`

It's currently render-blocking according to Google's PageSpeed Test and affecting page performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add async/defer attribute to the script.

```
<script async  src="https://cdn.domain.com/5670e553459091885818c74beba82.js"></script>
```

Or

```
 <script defer src="https://cdn.domain.com/5670e553459091885818c74beba82.js"></script>
```